# Are git conflicts less likely if I edit before or after somebody else's changes?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution

A colleague has a ticket that will be merged after mine (for the sake of the question, assume that's not changeable), and I need to make a change to a file they've changed.

Say the file with their changes is:

```
this line doesn't change

this line is edited

this is added
```

Is there a place in the file (assuming I can freely pick) that will reduce the possibility of merge conflicts for my colleague?

Comment: If you both add new code to the end of the file, then that will indeed result in a merge conflict. Though it is super trivial to resolve those kinds of merge conflicts, so no need to worry about it.

Comment: @Ôrel an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure. Also, where did I say I was afraid of conflicts or didn't know how to fix them?

Comment: @CoryKramer thanks for answering, care to put it in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes to lines that overlap or abut result in merge conflicts (with one exception noted below).  Changes to lines that do not overlap and do not "touch at the edges" do not produce merge conflicts.  There are "virtual" lines above the first line of the file, and after the last one, that always touch.

Hence, if you both start with:

```
the rain
in Spain
falls mainly
on the plain
```

and one commit "touches" the first line (only) to capitalize `the`, and the other commit "touches" the last line (only) to add a period at the end of the sentence, there will be no conflicts.  However, if someone decided to capitalize each first word of each line, there would be a conflict with the change that added the period at the end of the last line.

The exception to the overlaps-or-abuts rule occurs when both modifications change both series of input lines to the exact same output lines.  In this case, Git—or virtually any three-way merge algorithm except for "union merge"—takes just *one copy* of the change.

(Note that `git merge-file` does support union merge, but `git merge` does not.)